# SQLAlchemy Foreign Key to different models

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a Flask application and we use SQLAlchemy as ORM. There are two models: Entrie and Comment

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    to_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('??'))
```

The problem I am facing is that a comment can be referred to an entry but also to another comment and I don't have a clue how to write such relationships. My first attempt was creating a new class "Comentable" and inherit from this one but I want to find something more sophisticated

Have someone ever been in a similar situation? Any tip will be welcome. 
Thanks

Comment: Search for self-referential relationship in the SQLAlchemy docs.

Comment: I know how to deal with self-referential relationships in SQLAlchemy. The issue is that I want to refer either to a comment or an entry.

Comment: Add both `entry_id` and `comment_id` columns and constraint that doesn't allow both of them to be `NULL`.

Comment: Thought about it but I have seen people doing this technique in Django and I think it's simpler because you only care about the "to" attr instead of looking if there is comment_id or entry_id. Also you have to take care because only one of those will be NULL

Comment: You can try making a base `Replyable` class that `Entry` and `Comment` can inherit from, if you really want to have one foreign key.